# How to compare a element in String array in Android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I have a String array as follows:

```
String [] str_cmd_arr={"cmd1", "cmd2"};
```

Given that, "cmd1" will output "perform command 1", while "cmd2" will output  "perform command 2".

From my `str_cmd_arr`, how can I print the outputs individually in Java/Android?   Currently, I am using this code

```
for (int i=0;i<str_cmd_arr.length;i++){
    if(i<1){
        Log.d("TAG","perform command 1");
    }
    else{
        Log.d("TAG","perform command 2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The real solution here: use a Map, like

```
Map<String, String> commandsAndOutput = new HashMap<>();
commandsAndOutput.put("cmd1", "cmd1 output");
...
```

to later do

```
String output = commandsAndOutput.get("cmd1");
```

for example.

Another, probably more *sane* way here: consider using enums, like:

```
public enum Command {
  CMD1, CMD2;
}
```

if you are looking for more "compile time" support when making choices between different commands. As you now can write down:

```
Command cmd = ...
switch(cmd) {
  case(CMD1) : ...
```

But another word of warning: one should be careful about such enum/switching code. In most situations, a "real OO based" design that works with an abstract base class *Command* and specific subclasses is the better choice.

The real lesson here: you want to study some **basics**, like the tutorials found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). You see, there is no point in programming for Android ... if you don't know about such basic things such as Maps. In that sense it is hard to give you "good" advise, as the "good" stuff is that abstract base class solution - which seems to be completely beyond your current skills.

Comment: Thank you. But I want to print the output as my question.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your `if` statement with

```
if(str_cmd_arr[i]).equals("cmd1"){
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a loop and a `switch` statement

*for example*

```
for (int i=0;i<str_cmd_arr.length;i++){
    switch(str_cmd_arr[i]) {
        case "cmd1":
            Log.d("TAG","perform command 1");
        break;

        case "cmd2":    
            Log.d("TAG","perform command 2");
        break;
    }
}
```